# integral of squares roots over square roots

Tags: integration, radicals

I'm trying to do some exercises of this [site](https://www.math-exercises.com/limits-derivatives-integrals/indefinite-integral-of-a-function), but I'm stuck at the letter r one. Specifically this part $$
\int(...) -\frac{
    \sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{1} 6]{x\sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{3} ] {x^{-9}}}}
    {\sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{3}]{9x\sqrt[\leftroot{10} \uproot{3} ] {x^{10}}}}$$
Simplifying the numerator I got:
$$x^{-7/12}$$
The donominator:
$$9x^3$$
So I, now I thing we just need to subtract the bottom's exponent  from the top's right?
$$\frac{-7}{12} - 3 = \frac{-7 - 36}{12}= \frac{-43}{12}$$

Basically we got:
$$\frac{x^{-43/12}}{9}$$

Now the reverse power rule, I already added one to the exponent:
$$\frac{x^{-31/12}}{9}\frac{-31}{12} = \frac{12x^{-31/12}}{9*-31} = \frac{12x^{-31/12}}{-279}$$

This is wrong. The correct answer for this part only would be:
$$-\frac{4x^{-31/12}}{31}$$

It seems like I got the exponent correct. But somewhere in doing the reverse power rule I got lost in the sauce. Could someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Actually you have $3x^3$ in the denominator because $\sqrt9=3\,.$

Comment: ahh I forgot to apply the sqrt to to the 9. Thanks! But when we're do the the reverse power rule we would get this $$\frac{12x^{-31/12}}{-31*3}$$ , right? the denominator would still be wrong.

Comment: Marco, you need to simplify the fraction. $\dfrac{12}3=4$.

Comment: God, that's true. Now it's correct!! I have to always remember myself that. Thanks for your help man. Take care.